# How to optimize the mongodb aggregate query

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, nestjs

I have a collection which contains around 10.2M records.My aggregate query takes around 6s to send back a record.How do I optimize my aggregate query.? Indexes are defined on the token0address,token1address and timestamp fields.

Below is my query

```
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          token0Address: quoteCurrency,
        },
        {
          token1Address: quoteCurrency,
        },
      ],
      timestamp: {
        $gte: Number(historyDTO.from),
        $lte: Number(historyDTO.to),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: idObj,
      transactionDate: { $first: '$transactionDate' },
      timestamp: { $first: '$timestamp' },
      minimum_price: { $min: '$priceInToken0' },
      maximum_price: { $max: '$priceInToken0' },
      median_price: { $avg: '$priceInToken0' },
      open_price: { $first: '$priceInToken0' },
      close_price: { $last: '$priceInToken0' },
      volume: { $sum: '$priceInToken0' },
    },
  },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  { $skip: 0 },
  { $limit: Number(historyDTO.countback) },
```

idObj looks like this.It contains other combinations too

```
if (last === 'H') {
idObj = {
  day: { $dayOfYear: '$transactionDate' },
  hour: {
    $subtract: [
      { $hour: '$transactionDate' },
      { $mod: [{ $hour: '$transactionDate' }, parseInt(exceptLast)] },
    ],
  },
};
```

}

Comment: What's the purpose of `{ $skip: 0 }`?

Comment: Maybe try [$setWindowFields()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will mention some changes that I think could improve performance, however in general I will say this is pretty much optimized and I would personally not spend more time optimizing it unless it's an integral part of many process and each millisecond of runtime is important.

1. Create compound indexes for both fields `token0Address` and `token1Address`, Right now Mongo is using these indexes, however it then needs to fetch and match documents based on `timestamp`. If you could built both indexes as compound `{token0Address: 1, timestamp: 1}` then Mongo could finish the `$match` stage somewhat faster. (depending on the given range obviously and scale of the matched documents).
2. altering the `idObj` if possible, you mentioned `idObj` has different structures, maybe some of them have redundancies that could be eliminated, here we can't really do anything due to the dynamic usage of the `$mod` operator, Another possibility would be to preprocess the fields required ( for example in this case to save the `$hour` result so we stop using this operation ).
3. the last option is more of a trick but if you have known heuristics on your data distribution and queries you might be able to add earlier limits and process less data. this is usually not a realistic option especially with the somewhat low scale of your data.

Comment: We made some changes on the fields,Instead of indexes being implemented on token0address,token1address and timestamp,We applied indexes on pair field and timestamp and made them compound indexes,Additionally we used allowDisk:true.The response time changed from around 6s to  1s.